# Inner product in Hilbert spaces

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Considering a sequence $\{\boldsymbol{v}_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, and let $\{c_k\}_{k=1}^\infty \in \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$.

Then for all $\boldsymbol{v}\in\mathcal{H}$

$$ \langle \sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k \boldsymbol{v}_k, \boldsymbol{v}\rangle_\mathcal{H} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k \langle \boldsymbol{v}_k, \boldsymbol{v} \rangle _\mathcal{H} $$

Anyone who can assist me understanding this equal sign, or provide some intermediate results to prove this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you assuming $\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_kv_k$ converges? (I also don't see the need to break the vectors $c_kv_k$ up into the parts $c_k$ and $v_k$.)

Comment: @anon Yes, it is assumed that the series converges.

Comment: @user2520938 OP means $c_k$ is a function of $k\in\Bbb N$, and $\sum |c_k|^2<\infty$. (Writing the symbol $\Bbb N$ is superfluous since lowercase $\ell$ already signifies sequences.) I am inclined to believe Tryss below that $\ell^p(X)$ usually means $X$-valued things (which would make sense), meaning the OP is using the notation incorrectly.

Comment: @whacka Ah oke, thanks

Comment: Actually, when you write $l^2(X)$, it's usually a notation for a sequence of elements of $X$. The fact that it's a sequence (or a function of $k \in \mathbb{N}$) is already contained in the $l$ notation

Comment: @Tryss Ok thanks for that, that was also my first interpretation, but with that interpretation the question is trivial. But thanks for letting me know that this is indeed the conventional way of doing things

Answer (score 1):

The more direct thing to say is simply that if $w_k\to w$ in $\cal H$ then $\langle w_k,v\rangle\to\langle w,v\rangle$ in $\Bbb C$ for any chosen vector $v\in \cal H$. Then we can simply apply this to the sequence of partial sums.

To show $\|w_k-w\|\to0$ implies $|\langle w_k,v\rangle-\langle w,v\rangle|\to0$, notice that

$$|\langle w_k,v\rangle-\langle w,v\rangle|=|\langle w_k-w,v\rangle|\le \|w_k-w\|\cdot \|v\| $$

by the Cauchy-Schwarz identity.